# Expression for Derivative of Hyperparameter of Kernel with respect to New Data

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick, hyperparameter, derivative

I would like to determine how the hyperparameter will change when a new data is observed and the GP is updated with this new data.

Considering the following predictive distribution of the GP:

$$\mu(x^*)=K(x^*,X)^\top[K(X,X)+\sigma_n^2\mathbf{I}]^{-1} \mathbf{y_n}$$

and the squared exponential kernel:

$$K(x,x') = \sigma^2\exp\left(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\right)$$

How can I compute $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu}$?
Secondly is it right metric to compute to deremine the change in hyperparameter especially the lengthscale with respect to new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the question doesn't really make sense: $l$ is a hyperparameter of the problem and doesn't depend on the data at all, so $\frac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm d \mu}$ or any similar derivative is always just zero. I'm also not really sure what you mean by taking the derivative by $\mu$.

What it seems like you want is something like: "how should I locally update my hyperparameters given new data?" I'll answer a slightly different question: "how should I locally update my hyperparameters as my training dataset changes"? This question, though less natural, is much more amenable to taking derivatives.

I'm going to use $\theta$ to refer to the general set of parameters, both because $l$ is a bad variable name ($\ell$ is better...) and because you probably want to optimize more than one. One way to formalize this would be:

- Decide on a rule for picking $\theta$ given data: perhaps it's the $l$ that maximizes the marginal likelihood $p_\theta(\mathbf y \mid \mathbf X)$. You can call this
  \begin{align}
  \hat \theta
    &= \operatorname{argmax}_{\theta} \log p_\theta(\mathbf y \mid \mathbf X)
  \\&= \operatorname{argmax}_{\theta} - \mathbf y^T K_\theta(\mathbf X, \mathbf X)^{-1} \mathbf y - \tfrac12 \log\det K_\theta(\mathbf X, \mathbf X)
  .\end{align}
- You can then ask about how this $\hat \theta$ changes as your dataset $\mathbf X, \mathbf y$ changes. For instance,
  \begin{align}
       \frac{\mathrm d \hat\theta}{\mathrm d \mathbf y}
    &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d \mathbf y} \operatorname{argmax}_{\theta} \log p_\theta(\mathbf y \mid \mathbf X)
  .\end{align}

Now, this is well-defined. The problem is that taking that derivative is not trivial. (If there were a closed-form expression for $\hat\theta$, we could just write that out and differentiate it. But there almost never is.)

Instead, we can turn to the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) to see that
$$
\frac{\mathrm d \hat\theta}{\mathrm d \mathbf y} \Bigg\rvert_{\mathbf y = \mathbf y_0}
= - \left[ \frac{\partial^2 \log p_\theta(\mathbf y \mid \mathbf X)}{\partial \theta \, \partial\theta}  \right]^{-1} \frac{\partial^2 \log p_\theta(\mathbf y \mid \mathbf X)}{\partial \theta \, \partial \mathbf y} \Bigg\rvert_{\substack{\mathbf y = \mathbf y_0 \\\theta = \hat\theta(\mathbf y_0)}}
$$
or the same for $\mathbf X$.

Now, taking these derivates by hand will be somewhat unpleasant, but probably doable; there [are closed forms](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf) for the derivative of the matrix inverse and logdet, for instance.

If $\theta$ is more than a few parameters, this will also be quite computationally expensive in an automatic differentiation library like PyTorch, TensorFlow, or JAX – but for a handful of $\theta$, it shouldn't be *too* much work to implement. (For moderate-sized $\theta$, JAX might be most efficient, since unlike the other two it allows for forward-mode autodiff.)

(Double-check my application of the theorem here; I copied it from [a blog post](https://www.inference.vc/meta-learning-with-the-implicit-function-theorem/) rather than work it out again.)

Comment: You deliver the concept quite artistically in your answers! It will take some time for me to churn this. In the mean time I have the following statement and a question.

Comment: you mentioned "**how this $\hat \theta$ changes as your dataset $\mathbf X, \mathbf y$ changes**", actually, in my case, the dataset is same but a new datapoint is added. Does that change dataset as whole? so how hyperparameter change with respect to new incremental of data points. I wanna give some notion of "submodularity" meaning the small increments of new data dont change hyperparameters so much and the following is the reason why....(which is the equation i am looking for $d\theta / d\bf{y}$ but since $\bf{y}$ has little meaning in case of GP, hence I am using expected value $\mu$

Comment: also I always gets confused on marginal likelihood.In your example it is the likelihood integrated over the $\theta$ right?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER For the marginal likelihood, [here](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/4f13/1920/hyperparameters.pdf) is an explanation and example of using it.

Comment: Otherwise: In terms of adding a data point versus changing an existing one: I don't know if there's going to be a good derivative-based method for adding a single data point. The formula I derived above is for changing the entire dataset, but you could consider changing only a single $y$ / $X$ using these same types of formula. It doesn't quite answer what you're looking for, though.

Comment: Another option would be asking for something like _stability_ of the hyperparameter selection. I don't know if there's been work on that for GPs or not.

Comment: Actually after revisiting what I said, I realized I did not provide full context. Yes your derivation can be used directly. I shall be using GP's expected value or predicted mean as the new data point, so I can replace $\bf{y}$ with predicted GP mean $\mu$ I just need to find a way to cite you.

Comment: **some context** I have two expensive functions realized by (GP): GP1 & GP2. Both are used in conjuncture with Bayesian Optimization. Both start with same samples initially. In GP1 real data is being added, whatever BO suggests and in other, GP2, predicted mean of GP2 is used to update GP2 as real data. So in GP2 $\bf{y}$ becomes predicted $\mu$. Now I wanna compare how the suggestion from acquisition function of the two GP's diverge and wanna calculate this gap! "quite terrible right :)" So one metric is to see how kernel correlation gets affected $d\theta/ d\bf{y}$ and if [continued]

Comment: GP2's BO suggestion falls under some correlation length of GP1's BO suggestion then we can use this as the "Gap"

Comment: Also your answers to my previous questions have been quite helpful in getting me here!

Comment: so it took me some time to chrun your answer here, revisiting it I realised you mentioned ``l is a hyperparameter of the problem and doesn't depend on the data at all`` But isnt that what we are deriving? dont hyperparameters depend on data?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Not inherently: you can fix a hyperparameter beforehand and never change it. The "best" hyperparameter depends on the data, e.g. as the outcome of maximizing marginal likelihood, but you need to specify how you're selecting it in order for it to depend on the data.

Comment: Allright, it makes sense now, so we can simply "arbitrarily" select the hyperparameters and just keep using those. Wouldn't be wise option but nevertheless an option.